# New sub panel wire sizes

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I would like to install a small sub-panel in my basement. It will be approximately 55-60 feet from the main panel.

I will be running a fridge, some fluorescent lights, and occasionally some small appliances (meat grinder, deli slicer, etc.)

I was thinking a 30 Amp breaker off the main 200 Amp box and running four #8 wires in a 1" PVC conduit. (2 hot 1 neutral 1 ground.)  Am I OK with the #8 wires, or do I have to go to #6?

Answer (score 3):

For a 30A breaker, honestly, you're fine at #10 wire.  At that distance you don't need a wire size bump even for 120V loads.

You said the word "cable" which means several individual wires in a sheath. That's not what you want, it's very difficult to pull through a conduit.  Get individual wires, of type THHN (typically dual-labeled THWN-2). They will easily fit in 1" conduit.

Comment: i said cable because they are heavy wires,, but yes all separate,  thhn,, i was gifted a few reels of it years ago,,   the  fridge will be running pretty much all the time, but  just a few outlets and some 2x4 troffers for lighting,,   never gonna be running anything 220, so i figure,, fridge on one leg an the outlets and lights on the other,, and thank you for the answer